# @click from vuex does not work on the vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, datatable, vuex

This is from my store.

```js
getters: {
  getFormattedUsers (state) {
    state.users.forEach(v => {
      v.fullname = `${capitalize(v.fname)} ${capitalize(v.lname)}`
      v.created_from_now = moment(v.created_at).fromNow()
      v.approve_button = `<button @click="openApproveModal" class="btn btn-primary">Approve</button>`     
    })

    return state.users
  }
}
```

Now in my component (mounted property),

```js
async mounted () {
  await this.initializeUsers()

  $('#dataTable').DataTable({
    data: this.getFormattedUsers(),
    columns: [
      {data: 'fullname'},
      {data: 'username'},
      {data: 'is_approved'},
      {data: 'created_from_now'},
      {data: 'approve_button'}
    ]
  })
}
```

Supposedly, when you click on the **Approve Button**

```js
methods: {
  openApproveModal (id) {
    console.log('Approved!')
  }
}
```

But turns out, it logged nothing. The function was not called at all.

Moreover, this is what my component's table look like:

```html
 <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable">
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <th>Name</th>
       <th>Username</th>
       <th>Status</th>
       <th>Registration Date</th>
       <th width="5">Action</th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
 </table>
```

Comment: So you are saying like you are clicking the button from the vuex getters at the time the getters are called. Right?

Comment: yesyes, @Yahiya

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you shouldn't be modifying reactive state inside a getter. This can lead to infinite loops and in general is just a bad idea.

This is a red flag:

```js
v.approve_button = `<button @click="openApproveModal" class="btn btn-primary">Approve</button>`
```

I suppose you're injecting that into the DOM with `v-html`? That won't work. `v-html` only works with HTML but what you have is a Vue template.

I don't know what the full template is so I can't suggest a solution, but you should always avoid `v-html` at all costs (not only for the XSS concerns, but it usually indicates you're doing something against the "Vue way").

---

Here's a simplified demo of what you're trying to do:

```js
// Try to create a Vue button

function handleClick() {
  alert('You will not see this')
}

const app = document.querySelector('#app')
app.innerHTML = '<button @click="handleClick">Not Working</button>'

// Do it properly

const componentInstance = new Vue({
  template: '<button @click="handleClick">Working</button>',
  methods: {
    handleClick() {
      alert('Works!')
    }
  }
})

componentInstance.$mount()
app.appendChild(componentInstance.$el)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: I am not using v-html sir, I am however, using datatable using ajax property. This property has the value of the getters **getFormattedUsers()**

Comment: ` <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="">
               <thead>
                 <tr>
                   <th>Name</th>
                   <th>Username</th>
                   <th>Status</th>
                   <th>Registration Date</th>
                   <th width="5">Action</th>
                 </tr>
               </thead>
               <tbody></tbody>
             </table>`

Comment: Either way it still gets injected into the DOM via `innerHTML`. You can't just inject a Vue template into the DOM and expect it to work; at some point the element needs to be constructed with `new Vue()`. I'm not familiar with Datatables, but there would need to be some mechanism exposed by Datatables for you to render a custom table cell. You could instantiate the component and then mount the component into the table cell.

Comment: ok, I get your concern of not using v-html or what not, but why can't the button work? why can it not call the component's method even after render.

Comment: The `@click` syntax is a Vue feature and isn't standard HTML. Datatables is taking the Vue template string and treating it as if it were plain HTML. For it to actually work you need to construct a Vue component instance with the given template string. See my edit.